# RenderTransform flickering

Tags: silverlight

See the following code,
After I clicked the button, the listbox render several times.
How can I prevent Listbox flickering?
Is it possible to tell a control stop update/render?

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication52.MainPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Gray"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox"
             Background="White"
             Margin="100">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">

            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}"
                           Height="{Binding Height}"
                           Fill="{Binding Background}"
                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Scale}"
                                            ScaleY="{Binding Scale}" />
                            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}" />
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Left}"
                                                Y="{Binding Top}" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="test"
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public class ItemInfo
    {
        public double Left { get; set; }
        public double Top { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Angle { get; set; }
        public double Scale { get; set; }
        public Brush Background { get; set; }
    }

    ObservableCollection<ItemInfo> _items = new ObservableCollection<ItemInfo>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listbox.ItemsSource = _items;

    }

    Random random = new Random();
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            byte r = (byte)(random.NextDouble()*255);
            byte g = (byte)(random.NextDouble()*255);
            byte b = (byte)(random.NextDouble()*255);
            _items.Add(
                new ItemInfo
                {
                    Left = random.NextDouble() * 500,
                    Top = random.NextDouble() * 500,
                    Width = random.NextDouble() * 1000,
                    Height = random.NextDouble() * 1000,
                    Angle = random.NextDouble() * 359,
                    Scale = random.NextDouble() * 1,
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,r,g,b)),
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like that the flicker is caused by RenderTransform,
The ListBox would render once before the RenderTransform's binding get the correct binding value (using binding's fallback value)
and once again with updated binding value.
But still don't know how to workaround this problem.

Comment: found a similar problem http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/203971/477213.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to a separate ObservableCollection in that loop (that is not referenced/bound to the listbox). Then when the loop is done assign the listbox ItemsSource to the new observablecollection.

Comment: Thanks, I try to assign the listbox ItemsSource a new observablecollection. but it don't help.